# Fixed IP address reset everyday on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, ethernet, ip

I successfully managed to setup a fixed IP address on my server running Ubuntu Server 12.04 by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Then I ran the following command:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

And my fixed IP address 192.168.1.110 is properly applied when I check via `ifconfig`

**However, everyday at the same time, the address is being reset, and everytime the same address is assigned which is 192.168.1.134.**

If I run the `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` command again, my fixed IP address is back.

So my questions are:

- what could cause the IP address to be reset every day at the same time ?
- how can I fix that ? If possible, I'd like to avoid having to setup a daily script that runs the command.

Comment: Is there a DHCP server in your network, and if so, is 110 within the range of its DHCP pool?

Comment: @Jos I'm not sure I don't have the hand on the entire network. I've got access to two other machines. First one has got IP 192.169.1.133, second one is 192.168.1.135

Comment: If you don't know, you probably have DHCP, or otherwise there would be a systems admin who hands out static IP addresses.  Try a different static address far from 134, like 2 or 252, which hopefully falls outside the DHCP range.

Comment: @Jos Well yeah that's probably the problem indeed. Any way I can setup a fixed IP address when a DHCP is on the network ?

Comment: The DHCP range might be 130-140 or 100-240, there is no way to tell at this point. As I said, you should be able to pick an address outside that range by going as far from 134 as you can get.

Comment: @Jos OK I'll try 2 or 252 and see how it goes from here, feel free to post our conversation as an answer I'll upvote that

Answer (score 1):

Speculative answer: You probably have a DHCP server on your network, that periodically hands out "leases" on the addresses in its pool. Your static address ending in 110 is in that pool, but it hasn't been handed out by the DHCP so it takes it back, and gives you 134 in return.

Try a different IP address as far away from the DHCP pool as possible, which would be as low as 2 or as high as 252 (some conventions dictate that gateways have high numbers, although yours is 1).

Answer (score 0):

Check the gateway settings. On the gateway -router you will need to assign the same static ip address based on your server MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your router by typing your router ip into the address, usually 192.168.1.254 or 192.168.1.1

Look for something like DHCP server settings and turn the DHCP server off then see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for that, problem is I don't have router credentials.

Comment: The credentials are mostly username: admin and password also admin

Comment: Haha yeah already tried the default credentials found on the internet but seems like they've been changed

Comment: Turning off DHCP on the router is not a solution! Other devices may need it, and they won't be able to connect with DHCP off

Comment: I know it's not a solution, but if that helps then we at least have a starting point to work from.

Comment: Well yeah that's probably the problem indeed. Any way I can setup a fixed IP address when a DHCP is on the network ?

Comment: Yes, but your router probably doesn't like that.